# Copy data if all cells match

Tags: excel-formula

I have 4 columns and I need to get the data from 1 of those columns (3) to another (4) but to get that data to that column (4). That columns (4) header must be linked to a cell in another column (2) which has the same name as the header in (4) shown below.

example

```
Sku (1) Attribute(2) Attributeresult(3)    screensize(4)* 
123     Screen Size      22"                   22"         (match)
124     CPU              AMD                               (no match)  
125     CPU              Intel                             (no match) 
126     Screen Size      24"                   24"         (match)
```

*
Column 4 Header Has the same name as some cells in (2) cell but no spaces or caps which col2 has.

So I want to get data from (3) to go in to (4) if the names in (2) & (4 header) match. The position of the (4) will be determined by the SKU (1). Also (4) is the 1 of 500 columns in the same way

Hope this made sense

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, not clear at all. What is "all 3 cells must be link"? What is correct and what is not? Please edit your question, maybe produce a mockup example and post a screenshot of the expected result.

Comment: Why do the first and fourth rows get `Result`? It's not clear what the logic is and "3 cells must be link" is not much of an explanation.

Comment: I have updated this and  hopefully a little clearer now

Answer (score 0):

This formula should do:

```
=IF(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE($B2;" ";""))=D$1;$C2;"")
```

Using `LOWER` and `SUBSTITUTE` you delete any spaces from the value in B2 and also turn everything into lowercase letters. You can then compare this string to your column header in D1 and return only the values of those rows, that match your criteria.

Comment: Hi I tried this and this comes up with a error as if the formula hass an error in it. any idea#

Comment: =IF(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE($B2;" ";""))This part works but it seems the past is where the issue is. This =D$1;$C2;"")

Comment: First guess would be that maybe your Excel wants commas instead of semicolons or something to that extent, or that the references need adjusting depending on where and how you store your data. Please post the specific error message you are receiving and I'll give it another look